# How to plot sinusoidal and absolute functions?

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams

I have to draw this diagram

[image]

with plots of these three functions:

[image]

The code I already have is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel=$x(t)y(t)z(t)$,xmin=0, xmax=1,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2, grid=major];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but I don't know how to plot those functions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: This is very likely another homework question. I can't find the link right now, but I believe I saw the same question asked some days ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just type in your functions into `\addplot` once per each function. If things get too rough in terms of smoothness you can increase the number of samples per plot.(see the last one). That holds for many options such that if you give it in the axis options applies to all but you can locally overrride them.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$t$,ylabel={$x(t),y(t),z(t)$},
            xmin=0, xmax=1,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1.2, grid=major,no marks,domain=0:1,samples=100]
\addplot+[] {sin(180*pi*x))};
\addplot+[] {(sin(180*pi*x)))^2};
\addplot+[samples=250] {abs(sin(180*pi*x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]